# MongoDB find an object by specifying nested value

Tags: mongodb, meteor

```
[
{
    customer: {
        field 1: {},
        field 2: {},
        answers: {
            "BUSI_EXP": { "answered": true, "updated": "date" },
            "NEW_HOME": { "answered": true, "updated": "date" },
            "VEHICLE": { "answered": true, "updated": "date" }
        }
    }
},
{
    customer: {
        field 1: {},
        field 2: {},
        answers: {
            "BUSI_EXP": { "answered": false, "updated": "date" },
            "NEW_HOME": { "answered": false, "updated": "date" },
            "VEHICLE": { "answered": true, "updated": "date" }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Here's my customer collection. As you can see, it has an answers field that has an answered flag for each key. How do i get all customers who answered any of the answers as true ?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
    db.collectionname.find({ $or:[{"customer.answers.BUSI_EXP.answered": true},
{"customer.answers.NEW_HOME.answered": true},
{"customer.answers.VEHICLE.answered": true}});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just edited the question. I hadn't asked what i really wanted to.

Comment: Is there not a way to iterate over the keys ? This is a small part of the actual collection there are about 80 keys to the answers field

Comment: No, you have to specify keys with $or.